# Printing from windows service

Tags: c++, service, printing

I printing on Microsoft XPS Document Writer from windows service. Printing finished well (without any errors). Buf if I printing again on it (not even from service) it not printing. On print queue I can see that my first print job (system) with status Error and other jobs blocking buy it. How can I printing from service correctly?
I use CreateDC, StartDoc etc.

**Edit:**

```
void Print(const std::wstring& path)
{
    ...
    HDC hdcMXDW = CreateDC(L"WINSPOOL", printerName.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
    if (!hdcMXDW)
    {
        return;
    }

    DOCINFO docInfo = {
        sizeof(DOCINFO),
        L"emf_to_xps",
        xpsName.c_str(),
        NULL,
        0
    };

    if (StartDoc(hdcMXDW, &docInfo) > 0)
    {
        if (StartPage(hdcMXDW) > 0)
        {
            ...
            EndPage(hdcMXDW);
        }
        EndDoc(hdcMXDW);
    }
    DeleteDC(hdcMXDW);
}
```

All printing Api functions return good result.

Comment: You need to share the code you have implemented.

Comment: Microsoft very strongly discourages printing from a service and won't accept support calls about it.  Printer drivers are unsubtle chunks of code with many possible failure modes.  Accordingly the printing API can only report that a function failed, it cannot report why.  A printer driver is responsible for notifying the user about mishaps itself.  That cannot work in a service, such a notification is never visible.  Don't do it.

Comment: But printing Api always return good results.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using SetJob with parameter command JOB_CONTROL_DELETE after printing.